# Error when pull from remote branch

Tags: git, github

I was originally on my `master` branch.

Then, I **created a new branch:**

```
git branch my-other-branch
```

Then, after I made some changes on my project, I pushed this branch to `origin` to make it a **remote branch**:

```
git push origin my-other-branch
```

I guess now the `my-other-branch` is available to other team members to use.

After a while, I made some more changes, **added and committed** them, then I tried to **pull** from the **remote** branch:

```
git pull origin my-other-branch
```

I got the **error** :

> error: Failed connect to SERVER_NAME:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://SERVER_NAME/projects/bank_project/repositories/git/bank/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

**Why do I get that error, where am I wrong?**

(My Git version is 1.7.2.3, my OS is Linux/Ubuntu)

Comment: Seemw more like a proxy issue, as in http://forums.funtoo.org/viewtopic.php?id=224. What is your Os and what is your Git version?

Comment: My git version is 1.7.2.3 , my OS is Linux Ubuntu

Comment: So is it some kind of proxy config mishap, like described in the link? Something that a `env-update` could fix?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you make changes to your branch, push them to origin, make some more changes, then want to pull from origin?

Comment: @Gauthier, pull the changes made by other team members as my post said.

Comment: @Mellon: I see, I somehow assumed your origin was where you published your changes for others to access only.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will need to set up branch tracking. Please run the following

```
git branch --track my-other-branch origin/my-other branch
git pull origin my-otherbranch
```