# Git get remote branch locally that didn't previously exist?

Tags: git

I am wanting to bring a newly added remote branch into my local repository without interfering with my local branches. Is this possible?

When I do:

```
git branch -a
```

The new remote branch doesn't appear in the list. So if I try to fetch the origin/newremotebranch it says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: What if you just do `git fetch origin`? That should create new remote tracking branches for all existing remote branches.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were asking so I deleted my answer. Unfortunately, it looks like you were mid-comment when I deleted it! What was the output of the command, out of curiosity? Also, @GregHewgill's suggestion should work.

Comment: No yours did work. I had to do Greg Hewgills command first which updated the remote branches locally. Then I did your command and now it works.

Comment: Ah! Well, either of you should post an answer. Mine missed a step.

Comment: I posted an answer that should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command will update your remote tracking branches:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will create new remote tracking branches in your local repository for any remote branches that don't yet have one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply check out the remote branch:

`git checkout -b new-branch-name origin/newremotebranch`

Should start tracking, and you'll be able to fetch after that.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me: fatal "git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/newbranchname' which can not be resolved as commit?"

Comment: As per the comments, `git fetch origin` should make this possible.

Comment: git fetch origin will definitely fix it.  However, should you ever get a similar error after doing a git fetch, make sure you didn't make a typo.  I've gotten that error before by typing "orgin"

Answer (score 0):

You can even setup tracking. The commands - cf - [Error when pull from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532494/error-when-pull-from-remote-branch/8587103#8587103)

```
git branch --track my-other-branch origin/my-other branch
git pull origin my-otherbranch
```